# Translating DataCategory

Tags: metadata, translation

I am using Copado, but it does not matter. I know that DataCategory could be translated. However, I want to deploy this thru metadata.

I reviewed the metadata CustomObjectTranslation and Translations and I did not find references for this.

So, what is the metadata that contains the translation for DataCategory?

Comment: Unlike DataCategoryGroup, I don't see MDAPI supporting DataCategory in the [Metadata Coverage Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/58)